# Basic Angular JS refresh and keeping session

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, filter, refresh

This is a noob question, I understand very little about JS and Angular. (this is the first time I touch either).
But I need to get this thing working and I appreciate your help.

I have the script / HTML below, and it kinda works. But two things are missing:
1) It creates a new session for every refresh
2) It filters on 'facebook-post' and I want it to filter on 'facebook-post' or 'twitter-message'.

Please don't '-1' the question for being too basic (and it is..) but I've spent a whole day trying to solve it myself first. I realize I need to spend a few days to learn JS and Angular, I don't have a few days right now.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS, while touching the subject: What's the quickest way to learn JS and Angular? and I mean quick.. ;-)

THANK YOU!

HTML:
...

```
    < div ng-controller="getMessages ">  
     < ol>  
        < li ng-repeat="message in messages  | filter:{'object-type':'facebook-post'}">  
        < div class="message">  
            < div class="icon"><img src="{{message['icon-url']}}" alt="" /></div>  
            < div class="text">{{message.text}}</div>  
            < div class="clear"></div>  
        < /div>  
        < /li>  
     < /ol>
```

JS:

```
    function getJsonData($scope, $http, $filter) {
    $http({
        url : "some-url",
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        crossDomain : 'true',
        method : 'GET',
        data : {},      
        headers : {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
        }
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.messages = data; //update_messages(data, $filter);

    });
    }

function getMessages($scope, $http, $timeout, $filter) {
    // initial call on load of page
    getJsonData($scope, $http, $filter);
    // polled call in specific intervals
    var poll = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            getJsonData($scope, $http, $filter);
            poll();
        }, 10000);
    };
    poll();
}
```

Comment: You don't get minused for asking newbie questions. You get them for asking bad questions (no attempts to solve the problem yourself, expecting others to write your code for you, etc.). The mere fact that you **tried** to solve the question yourself is enough to gurentee you won't get minused (that's beside the fact that the post is very clear and you provide exactly the right amount of code)

Comment: @yuvi Thanks. Better safe than sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

For point number 2 you can use a filter function:

View:

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages  | filter:socialMedia">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.socialMedia= function(media){
   return media == 'facebook-post' || media == 'twitter-message';
```

};

Not sure I understand question number 1 about the multiple sessions.

As for learning angular I quite like [ng-book](https://www.ng-book.com/) and [Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/) have a number of good courses (I have no affiliation to either but they helped me get up to speed).

Comment: thanks. Works. Now about that session thing... :-) my code polls on the data (REST/JSON), but unfortunately, it doesn't put the cookie / jsessionid on the request. The server creates a new session every time, and returns it in the response. How do I take that session data and put it as part of the request? (see code above)